# When i Run below code it runs perfectly on Windows but not working on macOS Big Sur - Python, PyQt5, openCV

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pyqt5

This code makes the application not responding on macOS 11.2.2 but works fine on Windows 10.

This GUI simple application to capture images from a webcam and saving that image.
I'm not getting any error when I run this code but when I click on SHOW button application became not responding.

SHOW button - Turns ON the webcam.

main.py

```
import sys
import cv2

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
import datetime


class tehseencode(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(tehseencode, self).__init__()

        loadUi('camera.ui', self)
        self.logic = 0
        self.SHOW.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.ExitClicked)

        self.TEXT.setText('Kindly Press "SHOW" to connect with webcam.')
        self.CAPTURE.clicked.connect(self.CaptureClicked)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def onClicked(self):
        self.TEXT.setText('Kindly Press "Capture Image" to capture image.')

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while cap.isOpened():
            ret, frame = cap.read()

            if ret:

                self.displayImage(frame, 1)
                cv2.waitKey()

                if self.logic == 2:
                    date = datetime.datetime.now()
                    NAME = 'Image/img_%s%s%sT%s%s%s.png' % (date.year, date.month, date.day, date.hour, date.minute, date.second)
                    print(NAME)
                    cv2.imwrite(NAME, frame)

                    self.logic = 1
                    self.TEXT.setText('your Image Saved, For another image press again "Capture Button')

            else:
                print('return not found')

        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    def ExitClicked(self):
        cap.close()
        window.close()

    def CaptureClicked(self):
        self.logic = 2

    def displayImage(self, img, window=1):
        qformat = QImage.Format_Indexed8

        if len(img.shape) == 3:
            if img.shape[2] == 4:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGBA888

            else:
                qformat = QImage.Format_RGB888

        img = QImage(img, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], qformat)
        img = img.rgbSwapped()
        self.imgLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(img))
        self.imgLabel.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = tehseencode()
window.show()

try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print('exiting')
```

camera.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Dialog</class>
 <widget class="QDialog" name="Dialog">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>790</width>
    <height>550</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Dialog</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTextBrowser" name="TEXT">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>441</width>
     <height>81</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="Exit">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>540</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>71</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Exit GUI</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="SHOW">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>160</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>71</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Show</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="CAPTURE">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>50</x>
     <y>250</y>
     <width>161</width>
     <height>71</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Capture Image</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="imgLabel">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>300</x>
     <y>130</y>
     <width>441</width>
     <height>401</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShape">
    <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="frameShadow">
    <enum>QFrame::Sunken</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="lineWidth">
    <number>5</number>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string/>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: the onClicked handler, like all handlers, MUST return quickly. your doesn't.